# Conditional choices should be either or

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, logic, conditional-statements

This is an example how the code exist currently : http://jsfiddle.net/rym2g/

The only thing I need it to do now is based on the choice that was made make sure that it is the only choice available... for example:

**who are you?**

- jim
- kyle
- becky

(you chose becky)

display becky's form

(you decided that you wanted to choose kyle instead of becky)

hide becky's form and display kyle's form only

Hope I've explained myself well enough.

```
<form>
    <ul class="form-nav">
        <li><a href="#a-1">AAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a-2">BBB</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-1">
    <ul class="form-nav">
        <li><a href="#a-1-1">aaa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a-1-2">bbb</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-1-1">
    <p>A-1-1</p>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-1-2">
    <p>A-1-2</p>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-2">
    <ul class="form-nav">
        <li><a href="#a-2-1">111</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a-2-2">222</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-2-1">
    <p>A-2-1</p>
</form>

<form class="hidden" id="a-2-2">
    <p>A-2-2</p>
</form>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul.form-nav a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = event.target.href.replace(/^[^#]+/, "");
    console.log("Going to: " + id);
    $(id).show().focus();
});
```

Comment: I'd like to hide only the option that is not selected based on what option was chose. http://jsfiddle.net/3qmeV/  So, the questions are fine to be displayed because they will serve as an pseudo nav to navigate back and forth between options. We should not be able to see two different options at the same time.

Comment: ah, never mind, my comment is wrong, deleting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways, but this is the simplest given what you are doing:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul.form-nav a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = event.target.href.replace(/^[^#]+/, "");
    console.log("Going to: " + id);
    // Hide forms that do not have the selected id
    $('form.hidden').not(id).hide();
    // Show the appropriate form
    $(id).show().focus();
});
```

View the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mMyLW/)

Comment: Hi Cale_b,  Thanks for your reply... your code works well but I am looking for a different effect. Maybe this will give you a better understanding of what I am trying to accomplish.  So, the questions are fine to be displayed because they will serve as an pseudo nav to navigate back and forth between options. We should not be able to see two different options at the same time. http://jsfiddle.net/3qmeV/

Comment: Then change `$('form.hidden')` to simply `$('form')`, and it hides *all other* sets of questions.

Comment: Maybe I need to write the whole thing up better, when i just appy $('form') to the code it hides all questions. I need to hide/show answer or question depending on answer in question above on the same page http://jsfiddle.net/3qmeV/

Comment: Still looking for a solution.

Comment: @KylePoyser - Please edit your question.  I don't understand what you are looking for, or how it differs from the answer(s) I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I have arrived to this following code.  All I need to do now is make sure that all of the questions stay visible given the path that the user is on. This way the user can go backward or forward if he/she chooses a different path.

I hope that I've made myself clear.  Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XuVUb/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_table(id){
  document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table11').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table12').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table13').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table14').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table15').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table16').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table2').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table21').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table22').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table23').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table24').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table25').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table26').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table3').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table'+id).style.display='block';
}
</script>
```