# All questions must stay visible depending on the user's path

Tags: javascript, forms, conditional-statements

I have this quote form that is pretty extensive...  All I need to do now is add some code that wi let the questions remain visible instead of hiding it after a selection is made.

i.e 
User will be in either a Business path (all table1,11,12,13,14,15,16), a Resident's path (all table2,21,22,23,24,25,26, or a I have a list path (all table3).

**Here is my fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/XuVUb/

**snippet of code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_table(id){
  document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table11').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table12').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table13').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table14').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table15').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table16').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table2').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table21').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table22').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table23').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table24').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table25').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table26').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table3').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table'+id).style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you asking?

Comment: Okay so one question takes you to the next http://jsfiddle.net/XuVUb/ All I need to do now is add some code that wi let the questions remain visible instead of hiding it after a selection is made.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but do you want to show questions, one after another, but instead of replacing the answered question with the next question, you want to keep the answered question and show a new one below it? In that case, just don't hide them again.

Comment: That's exactly it! but how do I do this with the code I have in place? http://jsfiddle.net/XuVUb/

Comment: I posted an answer. In the future, try to ask a clear question, and formulate it in such a way that it could be useful to others. This is a site with answers to questions, not a forum. If you do, you will get more up-votes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional choices should be either or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897049/conditional-choices-should-be-either-or)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/S9bSe/

HTML:

```
<div class="level-1">
    <p>Are you dead or alive?</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#dead" data-level="2">Dead</a></li>
        <li><a href="#alive" data-level="2">Alive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#schrodingers_cat" data-level="2">Both</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="dead" class="hidden level-2">
        <p>Do you have physical form?</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#corpse" data-level="3">Yes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ghost" data-level="3">No</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="corpse" class="hidden level-3">
            <p>You are a corpse</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ghost" class="hidden level-3">
            <p>You are a ghost</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="alive" class="hidden level-2">
        <p>Do you have 9 lives?</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#regular_cat" data-level="3">Yes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#maybe_human" data-level="3">No</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="regular_cat" class="hidden level-3">
            <p>You are a cat</p>
        </div>
        <div id="maybe_human" class="hidden level-3">
            <p>You might be human</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="schrodingers_cat" class="hidden level-2">
        <p>You are a cat and you belong to Schrödinger</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript (with jQuery)

```
$("a").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var level = $(this).data("level");
    $(".level-" + level).addClass("hidden");
    $(id).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Please excuse me for introducing jQuery, but it should at least make it clear how one might solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Josef, This really looks great! I'm currently running the latest version of jQuery and my website is bootstrapped.  Just wondering if I will have any problems loading jQuery 1.11.0?  Here is a link to my website I am currently migrating to WordPress. http://testing.printlabelandmail.com/

Comment: Look, this is going a little too far. I'm here to help you learn, if that's what you want. You already have three questions about the same thing. If you want someone to work for you, hire someone. Frankly my feeling is that if you are not willing to figure this out and learn you probably shouldn't be building a website.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I obviously know a bit more about building websites than you think.  If you don't like my questions, don't answer... I've been working on this problem for the longest and wanted to make sure it gets complete.  Infact, you could use a little help revamping your website.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across as rude, that was not my intention. Best of luck with your project.